# how can php know which html-file called it

Tags: php, html

If we have 2 html files (i.e. one.html and two.html) and within both we have a form which calls the same php file on submit, like:

```
<form method="post" action="example.php">
```

, how can example.php know which html file called it?

I'm new to php so any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

The `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable, while not trustworthy from a security standpoint, will provide you what you want in most cases.

You could also put a hidden input in your form and pass a variable with the form name or some id that you could use.

Comment: Thanks gview. That worked great, but only on the first click, as it creates another problem. Since example.php validates input, and if not valid, it outputs the form for new submission, after the first click, the referring page is no more one.html or two.html, but the example.php itself, which creates an error. 
I tried:
     if (!isset($_SESSION['callPage'])) {$_SESSION['callPage'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];}
 $strHTMLfile = file_get_contents($_SESSION['callPage']);
, but that didn't work. Maybe I'm not using the $_SESSION in a proper way ... ?

Comment: Could you please provide any references for "not trustworthy from a security standpoint" point, or elaborate on the same. Thanks.

Comment: @Vlad: The http_referer is provided by the browser.  Anything that comes from any user can be tampered/spoofed.  For that reason it can not be trusted information from a security standpoint.  For example, I have seen systems in the past where access was actually secured by the referer.  Needless to say those who figure this out need only spoof the required referer and they gain access to the page directly.

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to solve this problem. It is possible to read the referer from `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Or you set a parameter in your form to identify from where you come.

`<form method="post" action="example.php?id=xy">`

in your `example.php` you can read the `$_GET['id']` and do something with a if statement or a switch.

Comment: Or add a `<input type="hidden" name="coming_from" value="this_or_that_page">` to the form, and get it in `$_POST['coming_from']`.